# Lazily partition sequence with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following extension method to find an element within a sequence, and then return two `IEnumerable<T>`s: one containing all the elements before that element, and one containing the element and everything that follows. I would prefer if the method were lazy, but I haven't figured out a way to do that. Can anyone come up with a solution?

```
public static PartitionTuple<T> Partition<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Func<T, bool> partition)
{
    var a = sequence.ToArray();
    return new PartitionTuple<T>
    {
        Before = a.TakeWhile(v => !partition(v)),
        After = a.SkipWhile(v => !partition(v))
    };
}
```

Doing `sequence.ToArray()` immediately defeats the laziness requirement. However, without that line, an expensive-to-iterate `sequence` may be iterated over twice. And, depending on what the calling code does, many more times.

Comment: Is `partition(v)` always going to be `true` after the division point?

Comment: No. You can assume that `partition(v)` will return `true` zero or one times.

Comment: I am not sure what type of laziness do you want? When it suppose to be called `sequence.ToArray()`? (Which stage of caller request?)

Comment: I think I should remove the `ToArray`. :/ It's not important to the question. What I have up there does the job, but isn't lazy. I would like to rewrite the method, to *be* lazy.

Comment: You mean, not to apply `a.TakeWhile(...` and `a.SkipWhile(...` until someone really enumerates the query?

Comment: Correct. My preference would be to iterate over `sequence` exactly once from end-to-end. --Or less, if the caller only does `result.Before.ToArray()`, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting problem and to get it right, you have to know what "right" is. For the semantics of the operation, I think that this definition makes sense:

- The source sequence is only enumerated once even though the resulting sequences are enumerated several times.
- The source sequence isn't enumerated until one of the results is enumerated.
- Each of the results should be possible to enumerate independently.
- If the source sequence changes, it is undefined what will happen.

I'm not entirely sure I got the handling of the matching object right, but I hope you get the idea. I'm deferring a lot of the work to the `PartitionTuple<T>` class to be able to be lazy.

```
public class PartitionTuple<T>
{
  IEnumerable<T> source;
  IList<T> before, after;
  Func<T, bool> partition;

  public PartitionTuple(IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> partition)
  {
    this.source = source;
    this.partition = partition;
  }

  private void EnsureMaterialized()
  {
    if(before == null)
    {
      before = new List<T>();
      after = new List<T>();

      using(var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
      {
        while(enumerator.MoveNext() && !partition(enumerator.Current))
        {
          before.Add(enumerator.Current);   
        }

        while(!partition(enumerator.Current) && enumerator.MoveNext());

        while(enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
          after.Add(enumerator.Current);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public IEnumerable<T> Before 
  { 
    get
    {
      EnsureMaterialized();
      return before;
    }
  }

  public IEnumerable<T> After
  {
    get
    {
      EnsureMaterialized();
      return after;
    }
  }
}

public static class Extensions
{
  public static PartitionTuple<T> Partition<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Func<T, bool> partition)
  {
    return new PartitionTuple<T>(sequence, partition);
  }
}
```

Comment: Now that is an interesting idea. I hadn't thought to defer the work to `PartitionTuple`.

Comment: This is still iterating the whole source enumerable, isn't it?

Comment: +1 for your post even without the code. The request goes against general LINQ behaviour, so it's important to specify exactly how it does behave.

Comment: @Jacob: It is. If the caller only wants to use `Before`, it ends up iterating over `After` as well. However, it gives me an idea on how to implement what I want. Also, it's better than what I had. :)

Comment: I know that it might create `After` even if it is not needed. It is of course possible to solve, but that would mean holding on to the open enumerator which would require `PartitionTuple<T>` to implement `IDisposable`. If it is an important use case it might be worth it, but it would make `PartitionTuple<T>` considerably harder to use.

Comment: Agreed. I'm not complaining. :) --I'm using yours as-is, since I quickly discovered I had to implement `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `Lazy` object to ensure that the source sequence isn't converted to an array until one of the two partitions is iterated:

```
public static PartitionTuple<T> Partition<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Func<T, bool> partition)
{
    var lazy = new Lazy<IEnumerable<T>>(() => sequence.ToArray());
    return new PartitionTuple<T>
    {
        Before = lazy.MapLazySequence(s => s.TakeWhile(v => !partition(v))),
        After = lazy.MapLazySequence(s => s.SkipWhile(v => !partition(v)))
    };
}
```

We'll use this method to defer evaluating the lazy until the sequence itself is iterated:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> MapLazySequence<TSource, TResult>(
    this Lazy<IEnumerable<TSource>> lazy, 
    Func<IEnumerable<TSource>, IEnumerable<TResult>> filter)
{
    foreach (var item in filter(lazy.Value))
        yield return item;
}
```

Comment: But isn't the access to lazy.Value.TakeWhile triggering the enumeration when returning the result from Partitiion<T> method?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generic solution that will memoize any `IEnumerable<T>` to ensure it's only iterated once,  without forcing the whole thing to iterate:

```
public class MemoizedEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IDisposable
{
   private readonly IEnumerator<T> _childEnumerator;
   private readonly List<T> _itemCache = new List<T>();

   public MemoizedEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> enumerableToMemoize)
   {
       _childEnumerator = enumerableToMemoize.GetEnumerator();
   }

   public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
   {
       return _itemCache.Concat(EnumerateOnce()).GetEnumerator();
   }

   public void Dispose()
   {
       _childEnumerator.Dispose();
   }

   private IEnumerable<T> EnumerateOnce()
   {
       while (_childEnumerator.MoveNext())
       {
           _itemCache.Add(_childEnumerator.Current);
           yield return _childEnumerator.Current;
       }
   }

   IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
   {
       return GetEnumerator();
   }
}

public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Memoize<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        return new MemoizedEnumerable<T>(enumerable);
    }
}
```

To use it for your partitioning problem, do this:

```
var memoized = sequence.Memoize();
return new PartitionTuple<T>
{
    Before = memoized.TakeWhile(v => !partition(v)),
    After = memoized.SkipWhile(v => !partition(v))
};
```

This will only iterate `sequence` a maximum of one time.

Comment: Shouldn't `MemoizedEnumerable<T>` implement `IDisposable` and dispose the `_childEnumerator`?

Comment: I don't think that's a necessity. You could leave it up to the GC. `IDisposable` would just allow you to more deterministic with the cleanup.

Comment: I think that whenever anything implements `IDisposable` it should be disposed of properly - even though it probably won't matter on most sequences.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean, and you're right. Will update my code.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you just return some object of your custom class, which implements `IEnumerable<T>` but also provides the results on enumeration demand only.

You can also implement `IQueryable<T>` (inherits IEnumerable) instead of `IEnumerable<T>`, but it's rather needed for building reach functionality with queries like the one, which `linq for sql` provides: database query being executed only on the final enumeration request.

Comment: There's no need to involve `IQueryable<T>`. That's only needed when you want to preserve the expression tree of the query for translation to something else (e.g. SQL).

Comment: Thanks. But that's still possible (due to `IQueryable<T>` inheritance from `IEnumerable<T>` anyway), however, of course, might be just the second one.